# Can't use map function inside React render

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to use `map()` function to iterate over a `3D` array in `Reacts'` `render` method, but somehow it is not working and `webpack` complaints that there is an unexpected token. Here is the full code of my class:

```
class ExpressionGraph extends Component {
render() {
  const offsetX = - window.innerWidth / 4;
  const offsetY = - window.innerHeight / 4;
const x = 20;
const y = 20;
console.log(test_data["data"]);
const data = test_data["data"];

return (
  <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
    <Layer offsetX={offsetX} offsetY={offsetY}>

not working -------> data.map((typeArr, idx) => {

        console.log(typeArr);
        console.log(idx);
        typeArr.map((neuronArr, typeIdx) => {
          const numOfPoints = neuronArr[0].length;
          const circleColor = Konva.Util.getRandomColor();
          [...Array(numOfPoints)].map((_, pointIdx) => {
            const x = neuronArr[0][pointIdx];
            const y = neuronArr[1][pointIdx];
            console.log("x: " + x);
            console.log("y: " + y);
            console.log("circleColor: " + circleColor);
            return <ColoredCircle x={x} y={y} color={circleColor}/>
          })
        })
      })
    </Layer>
  </Stage>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the console logs as well.

Comment: You need to wrap it in `{}` brackets like `{data.map((typeArr, idx) => { ...})}`. But you have too much nested `map` so syntax is not the only problem you have

Comment: @Prakashsharma is right.

Comment: @Prakashsharma why several nested maps is considered a bad practice, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko I am not saying it is bad practice. I mean your code will not render array of `ColoredCircle` elements because of nested `map`.

Comment: Yes, it does not. I do not know why. Thinking of asking a separate question...

Comment: Actually adding just 'return' before `[...Array(numOfPoints)].map(` solved this issue of not rendering

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your map statement within `{}`

```
   {data.map((typeArr, idx) => {

    console.log(typeArr);
    console.log(idx);
    typeArr.map((neuronArr, typeIdx) => {
      const numOfPoints = neuronArr[0].length;
      const circleColor = Konva.Util.getRandomColor();
      [...Array(numOfPoints)].map((_, pointIdx) => {
        const x = neuronArr[0][pointIdx];
        const y = neuronArr[1][pointIdx];
        console.log("x: " + x);
        console.log("y: " + y);
        console.log("circleColor: " + circleColor);
        return <ColoredCircle x={x} y={y} color={circleColor}/>
      })
    })
  })}
</Layer>
```